# How to generate documentation for ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I remember the docs of threejs is based on sphinx, but I cannot find the .rst files.

How the documentation of threejs generated?

Is written in html directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [written in html directly](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/docs/api/cameras/Camera.html). But there is a bit of [markup for shortcuts](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/docs/page.js#L22-28).

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank u and I respect your opinion.

But I still think this is not flexible enough. Because it's not standard, so will be more difficult to republish to other formats. And its not friendly for some work, such as translate to other language.

Only my personal opinion, 

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind the next time I spend some time on improving the system.